# jquery ui accordion - flexible header styling

Tags: css, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using jquery UI accordion plugin but I need to be able to style each element separately. For example, I need different colors for headers (3 different colors would be used throughout the whole list). Setting up custom css classes for those elements, eg , doesn't work as it gets overwritten by UI css

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to override the jQuery UI CSS by Using !important.

e.g:

```
.header {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```